# Server - Client application and shared Linq to SQL generated classes

Tags: c#, rest, linq-to-sql, dbml

I'm working on a client-server application where server is running as REST service and is connected to SQL server. Classes are generated automatically from *.dbml file (LINQ->SQL).

My question is: Should I create new classes for data exchange between server and client or just use generated classes on both sides?

**Using of the same classes generated from *.dbml - PROS**

1. Better sustainability (data constrains are generated automatically)
2. Less probability of data errors caused by copying data between two data objects - (model is generated automatically and you don't have need to maintain copying of values from generated model to another)
3. Better speed. You have to create only one instance of model on server.

   - (when you have class A and class B representing the same data you have to create instance of both classes)

**Using of the same classes generated from *.dbml - CONS**

1. Client exactly know the db table structure and used datatypes

Comment: That is a reasonable summary of the pros and cons.

Comment: Another con for me is, that the client might use the model in different ways, e.g. for addresses where some fields may be required or not, which I would realize using different `required` definitions in annotations of the properties in the viewmodel.
Another con could be, that very often you don't only want to echange properties of one model, but a mixture of various .

Answer (score 0):

One "CON" you're missing is that using the the same model could mean you're transferring more data than is needed.

Using specific contracts between the client and server would mean only data the client needs is sent over the wire.